# Problemas em transferir dados tipo data do MSProject para Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Olá. Estou com problemas em transferir algumas datas tipo Baseline Start, Baseline Finish, Actual Start, Actual Finish do MSProject para uma planilha no excel. Aqui está o trecho do código.

```
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Prog As MSProject.Project
Dim Proj As MSProject.Application
Dim t As Task
Dim i As Long

[...]

For Each t In Prog.Tasks
    i = i + 1

    Set xlSheet = wb.Worksheets(6)
        xlSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = Proj.GetCellInfo(7, i).Task.Name
        xlSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = Mid((Proj.GetCellInfo(10, i).Task.BaselineStart), 1, 11)
        xlSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = Mid((Proj.GetCellInfo(11, i).Task.BaselineFinish), 1 , 11)
        xlSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = Mid((Proj.GetCellInfo(12, i).Task.ActualStart), 1 , 11)
        xlSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = Mid((Proj.GetCellInfo(13, i).Task.ActualFinish), 1 , 11)
        xlSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = Proj.GetCellInfo(14, i).Task.ResourceNames

Next t
```

Quando eu uso a substring mid, é para retirar os horários que vem junto com a data. Porém quando esta data é passada para a planilha no excel, ela vem com formato mm/dd/yyyy. Se eu não usar a substring, a data vem no formato dd/mm/yyyy porém com as horas.

Quando não uso uma substring, a data é passada assim 05/12/2016 08:00:00

Quando eu uso a função Mid, o valor fica assim.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, a data é passada para a planilha com o seguinte valor.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que poderia estar causando essa inversão no formato?

Comment: Se o Excel automaticamente converte a data para `"mm/dd/yyyy"`, provavelmente o seu sistema está configurado em Inglês, o que justificaria a mudança. Experimente colocar `xlSheet.Cells(i,2).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"` após a cópia dos dados.

Comment: Luiz, você está certo, meu sistema está em inglês. Porém sua solução funcionou quando coloquei o formato "mm/dd/yyyy". O motivo eu não sei.

Comment: O motivo é esse mesmo: a configuração do sistema em inglês (americano) espera a data com o mês antes do dia. Se funcionou como vc disse, provavelmente o sistema está em inglês e o Excel em português. Mas enfim, se funcionou, tá valendo. Eu vou postar como resposta pra ajudar outras pessoas no futuro. Aí, se você realmente achar que a resposta te ajudou, por favor considere [marcá-la como aceita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o seu sistema operacional está configurado em inglês Americano, já que é nessa configuração que se espera que a data seja fornecida com mês antes do dia (isto é, no formato `mm/dd/yyyy`).

O ideal seria você configurar o seu sistema para trabalhar no formato de datas do usuário (o Windows tem a configuração de localidade no Painel de Controle). Mas uma solução paliativa é você forçar a formatação no Excel. Use algo do tipo:

```
xlSheet.Cells(i,2).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

para definir uma formatação específica de uma célula. Como você mesmo já observou em comentários, talvez você deva indicar que o formato originalmente recebido é o americano e deixar o Excel tratar posteriormente (nesse caso, indique `"mm/dd/yyy"` mesmo no `NumberFormat`).